# How to verify a user is from one of my 6 domains

Tags: javascript, google-signin

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function onSignIn(googleUser) {
                var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
                console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); 
                console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());
                var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
                console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);

                if(id_token !="")
                {
                 window.location = 'support.php';
                }
              };
</script>
```

I have done quite a bit of searching and can't seem to find what I am looking for. The above code is what I have. What I need it to do is the following.

I have 6 domains that access this same site. I want to have it so that ONLY those six google domains can log in. If your email does not match one of the six domains, it will take you to an error page. How can I do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the PHP code  that you should have been trying? Or change your PHP tag.

Comment: This is just javascript

Comment: has php tag, but no php, does not have javascript tag but does have javascript. Syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

If you're actually looking for PHP and not javascript, then something like this should work:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$allowed = array('domain1.com', 'domain2.com', 'domain3.com');

// Make sure the address is valid
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
    $explodedEmail = explode('@', $email);
    $domain = array_pop($explodedEmail);

    if ( ! in_array($domain, $allowed))
    {
        // Not allowed
        header('Location: http://example.com/myOtherPage.php');
    }

}
```

Comment: I apologize for the misinformation. You're right, the code I posted is javascript. It is the code used for google login API. Your code on the other hand, DOES seem sound and it SHOULD work. Because I have

          if(id_token !="")
                {
                 window.location = 'support.php';
                }

it is going to allow any user who logs in with any domain through. But if I remove that piece of code, the page will not redirect anywhere. So I am unsure as to what is going on.